# Why do multiple keyboard inputs stop playing an action?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a simple character, who has simple animations. In the logic editor, I have a Keyboard sensor (<kbd>W</kbd>) *> And controller > Action actuator* set to *Loop stop*.

I did the same with another keyboard sensor (<kbd>S</kbd>). When I play the game and use <kbd>W</kbd> it's fine, and when I use <kbd>S</kbd> it is also fine. But when I press both of them (<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and let go of only one of them, the animation stops.

This ***only*** happens when I wait for a second after pressing one (<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>) and then press a second. In other words, the *game is fine until I press 2 of the functions at once*.

How can I let both <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> work fluently with *Loop Stop* enabled?

Comment: Please don't close question, like always, I tried to make it as clear as possible, I am in danger of being blocked!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but here's a guess anyway.. Does it work if you use an **or** controller instead of **and**?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! MAKE THIS AN ANSWER AND ILL PICK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because an *and* controller requires all connected sensors to be true to pass a signal to the actuator. An *or* controller requires that at least one of the inputs is true.

Think of it this way:

- An and controller requires both sensor 1 **and** sensor 2 to be true.
- An or controller requires either sensor 1 **or** sensor 2 to be true.

This is just [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations), see [the wiki for more details](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Controllers).